# PHP math need same number * 100

Tags: php

I need same number * 100, example:

```
0.436845270 * 100 = 43.684527, but I need exatcly like that: 43.6845270.
```

Other:

```
0.248958534 * 100 = 24.8958534, its ok.
```

What I need is exatcly same number * 100, even 0 at the end matters.

PHP Code:

```
$result = $something*100;
```

Comment: That's nice. So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Why would 0.248958534 * 100 = 0.248958534 ?! In what universe..

Comment: What do you dont understand? I need exatcly same number * 100, but PHP math: "0.436845270 * 100 = 43.684527", I need 0 in this case.

Comment: use it as a string.. not as float value..

Comment: @Burkhard Thanks. fixed now.

Comment: @JohnConde In this case I dont think any code which Im using is required, but: "$result = $something*100;"

Comment: @ArnasMarnas Specific code that you have tried and how exactly it is not working is pretty much always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format your number you should use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function to specify how many decimals you want to get.

```
number_format($yourNumber, 7, '.', '');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, but what if number length is changing? Like one time its .12345, another .123?

Comment: Its important because I use that with MD5 hash so I need exact number.

Comment: It'll always return your number with exactly 7 decimals (eg. .123 will become .1230000).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
string number_format (float $number, 7)
```

or

```
sprintf('%09.7f', $number);
```

if you always need a 9 digit decimal to a 2/7

otherwise:

```
$str = $number;
$digits = strlen($str) - 1;
$format = '%0' + $digits + '.' + ($digits - 2) + 'f';
sprintf($format,$number);
```

or

```
$str = $number;
$digits = strlen($str) - 1;
$str = number_format($number,($digits-2));
```

Comment: Format your answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. I reformat once.

Comment: sorry... added some stuff because asker clarified question in a comment